# JavaScript creates unwanted div onload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a shopping cart by scratch and want to implement a way to delete items from my cart by using a number inverval, but while setting that up I've ran into a problem. Since I'm now using variables to change my div depending on the numbers in an array, JavaScript creates a blank unwanted divs that is causing problems.

```
var imagevalue = "";
var namevalue = "";
var pricevalue = "";

function addItem(itemnum){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
   
    if(itemnum == "1"){
        imagevalue = "hoodie.png";
        namevalue = "Spartan Hoodie";
        pricevalue = "$50";
    }
    else if(itemnum == "2"){
        imagevalue = "longsleeve.png";
        namevalue = "Spartan Long-tee";
        pricevalue = "$30";
    }
    else if(itemnum == "3"){
        imagevalue = "cutoff.png";
        namevalue = "Spartan Cutoff";
        pricevalue = "$25";
    }
    else if(itemnum == "4"){
        imagevalue = "waterbottle.png";
        namevalue = "Spartan Bottle";
        pricevalue = "$15";
    }
    div.setAttribute('class', 'item');
    div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img"><img src="../images/` + imagevalue + `"></div>
            <div class="title">` + namevalue + `</div>
            <div class="price">` + pricevalue + `</div>
            <i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="deleteItem(` + itemnum + `)"></i>
       </div>`;
    document.getElementById("items").appendChild(div);
}
```

I haven't tried anything specific to fix it other than move stuff around to see if it fixes anything which since I'm here it hasn't. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the `setInterval` code that you're using to remove the divs?

Comment: Multiple calls to ``addItem` with the same item number will create new menu items. Is that the issue you are having a problem with, or does it have something to do with deleting items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible reason for this is that the itemnum parameter passed to the `addItem()` function is not matching any of the conditions in your if-else statements. As a result, the `imagevalue`, `namevalue`, and `pricevalue` variables remain empty, leading to the creation of a `div` with empty values.

you can add a default `else` case to handle situations where the itemnum doesn't match any of the defined cases